# How to set a GUID as ADO query parameters from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, guid, ado

MS Access allows the numeric type GUID (in German it's called 'Replikations-ID', so I guess in English that would be 'replication id') which is stored as a 16 byte binary field in the database.

I found how to access these fields in Delphi with [**TADOQuery**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery)/[**TADOTable**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOTable) using

```
(TheQuery.FieldByName('SomeGuidField') as TGUIDField).AsGuid;
```

But now I want to execute an SQL-Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeGuidField=:AGuid
```

I tried setting a [**TADOQuery.SQL**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOQuery.SQL) property to the above statement, but found no way to actually set the `AGuid` parameter such that the query can be opened. Whatever I tried resulted in the (ADO/COM) error

> No value given for one or more required parameters

For example:

```
TheQuery.ParamByName('AGuid').Value := QuotedString(GuidToStr(AGuid));
TheQuery.Open; // <<== crashes here
```

This doesn't work either:

```
TheQuery.ParamByName('AGuid').Value := GuidToStr(AGuid);
TheQuery.Open; // <<== crashes here
```

I had a look at how `TGuidField(...).AsGuid` works and found that it first converts the GUID to a string and then the string to a variant (and vice versa).

It works fine, if I always generate the SQL-Statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeGuidField='<a guid goes here>'
```

As I am passing that **TADOQuery** object around in the program I would like to only change the `AGuid`-Parameter to keep most methods agnostic on the actual SQL-Statement.

Is there any other way to set a GUID-Parameter than always change the complete SQL-Statement?

(It must be a GUID because I need a globally unique identifier to synchronize with other databases which are MS SQL or MS Access based.)

**Edit**
vradmilovic is right, this works:

```
TheQuery.ParamByName('AGuid').Value := GuidToStr(AGuid);
TheQuery.Open;
```

I don't understand why it didn't work the first time I tried it.

Comment: Wait, closed as too localized? I would have to strongly disagree. I should resurrect this question and cast a re-open vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct way to set parameters with ADO. The message you get is most probably due to typo with some of fields (you get same message if field does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth I'm using GUIDs but I save them in DB as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should not save them as strings. You should use uniqueidentifier. The two functions to use are GUIDToString and StringToGUID (not the str-ones).

If you copy values from the active directory (comes as ftVarBytes) you can use assign which does the magic for you:

```
QueryIns.Parameters.ParamByName('GUID').Assign(Query.FieldByName('objectGUID'));
```

If you want to extract the objectGUID from AD you need to cast the objectGUID to uniqueidentifier:

```
Query.SQL.Add('select cast(objectGUID as uniqueidentifier) as objectGUID');
Query.SQL.Add('from vwADGroups');
Query.Open;
while not Query.Eof do begin
  Index := List.IndexOfName(Query.FieldByName('objectGUID').AsString);
  //...
end;
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are sure the parameter is a TGuid, then the following should work :

```
TGuidField(TheQuery.ParamByName('AGuid')).AsGuid
```

Although this does a GuidToString internally, so the problem maybe the same. Worth a try!

Comment: results in an access violation

Comment: In ADO, `ParamByName()` returns a `TParameter`, which is not derived from `TField` and cannot be casted to `TGuidField`.